# How to get a total training set loss for an epoch using Tensorflow Estimator api

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm looking for a way to implement a search of learning rate as described here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01186.pdf .

To get this implemented I need to have a way to get loss for a single epoch for multiple learning rates. I'm thinking about creating a SessionRunHook and simply take an average out of the loss for each step, it won't be exact as last step most likely won't have batch_size of elements but it should be good enough.

Do you have such SessionRunHook implemented or knows how to access loss or / and batch size during training.

Answer (score 2):

What I come up with is this, it does not account for the last mini batch that can be smaller but since I'm not running the whole training set it should be okey:

```
class RecordLossHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
  def __init__(self, loss_name):
    self.loss_name = loss_name

  def begin(self):
    self._loss_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_element(self.loss_name+":0")
    self.loss_summed = 0
    self.batch_count = 0

  def before_run(self, run_context):
    return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self._loss_tensor)

  def after_run(self, run_context,  run_values):
    self.loss_summed += run_values.results
    self.batch_count += 1 
    self.loss = self.loss_summed/self.batch_count
```

However if anyone has better hook that does account for the last minibatch I'm happy to accept such answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work as well:

```
epoch_loss = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)
update_epoch_loss = tf.assign_add(epoch_loss, loss_op)
reset_epoch_loss = tf.variables_initializer([epoch_loss])


for epoch in num_epochs:

    sess.run(reset_epoch_loss)

    for step in steps_per_epoch:
        sess.run([train_op, update_epoch_loss])

    this_epoch_loss = sess.run(epoch_loss)
```